# Create a server to host a website using old pc

Tags: linux, mysql, php, website, html

Good Afternoon, sorry if its not the right place to ask this question.

I have to make a `project`, a `website`, for university, and the client wants to see the progress until the project is finished.
The problem is, I don't have that much money to buy a host and searching for some solutions I found that is possible to create a `server` for free using and `old pc`. 
My question is how do I do that same ´server´? And I can also host the `database`?
The `website` is going to be made using `PHP`,`MySQL`,`HTML`, and some `JavaScript`.

P.S: I have some knowledge about `linux distros`, like `Ubuntu`, so if its necessary use that `SO`, that's not a problem.

Comment: https://lowendbox.com/

Answer (score -1):

The two key concepts to research on the internet are Wampserver and Lampserver. The final choice for which "distro" you will use, will depend on the capability of your "old pc" and how complicated it gets.

Both the "Wampserver" and "Lampserver" are a collection of software packages that will include Apache webserver, Mysql database server and PHP. The former runs on Windows and the latter runs on Linux. Also, in the case of the latter, you can search for complete solutions that include not only the Lamp server but the Linux operating system as well.

Any of them can be configured to act as a production server which allows people from outside to view websites on your web server.

If you are reasonably comfortable with Linux, then a very good choice would be Turnkey Linux Lampserver. Download the ISO and create a bootable CD or USB dongle with it (see LiLo). Start your old PC with it and after the installation is complete you will have a Webserver that you can manage with Webmin.

If your old PC already runs Windows, you could download a suitable Wampserver. Good Wampserver distros include Bitnami, Xampp and Wampserver. You will need to match the capability of your PC with the distro. You may need two or three attempts at installing a Wampserver before you find one that suits an "old Pc" - eg 32bit Windows XP.

This information should get you going. You may have more detailed questions in the future.